# Android shape drawable color is displayed incorrectly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-shapedrawable

I'm trying to draw a simple circle and use it as a background to an ImageView the problem is the circle is drawn with different color whenever I open the application, here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="oval">

    <size
        android:width="16dp"
        android:height="16dp"
    />


    <solid android:color="#FFF6621F"/>
```

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/counterBackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_circle"/>
```

Comment: can you post an output and whats the color your are expecting

Comment: it shows random colors for the circle, same output if you add no solid item in the shape

Comment: so you are saying insted of Red oval you get random colors ? I don't think so may be you are setting background again problematically, unless it should be red in color

Comment: Unless you happened to only copy a part of it, your shape XML file is invalid since the `<shape>` tag is unclosed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code....

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="300dp"
     android:layout_height="300dp"
     android:layout_gravity="center">

         <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/imgview"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imgview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview);

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_blogger);

        imgview.setImageBitmap(getCircleBitmap(bm));

    }

    private Bitmap getCircleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        final Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = Color.RED;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawOval(rectF, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        bitmap.recycle();
        return output;
    }
}
```

You can use getCircleBitmap() method for make ImageView in circle shape.